# Extensions between integral domains give extensions of fields of the same degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Assume that $S \subset R$ is a ring extension where, both $S$, $R$ are integral domains. Furthermore, assume that $R$ is a free $S$-module of rank $n$. Is it true that the extension of fields $\mathrm{Quot}(S) \subset \mathrm{Quot}(R)$ is of degree $n$? If yes, how do we prove that?

Comment: Why close & downvote this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Show that $\text{Quot}(R) \xleftarrow{\cong} R\otimes_S \text{Quot}(S)$; in words, it suffices to have all elements of $S\setminus\{0\}$ invertible to conclude that all elements of $R\setminus\{0\}$ are invertible. Use that $R$ is integral over $S$ for that. This reduces the question to the preservation of degree under base extension. Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't get where the above isomoprhism helps us? It's an isomorphism of abelian groups, isn't it?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris It's a morphism of $\text{Quot}(S)$-algebras, and the left hand side has rank $n$ over $\text{Quot}(S)$ by the preservation of degree under base extension - does this make things clearer?

Comment: yeap, I think! I'll check it closer! Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome :)